# Send Date from bootstrap datepicker to Spring Controller with TimeZone

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, bootstrap-datepicker

1) on jsp page:

```
<input class="datepicker"/>     -- 10.02.2017
```

jQuery:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
        'format': 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    });
```

2) Controller - Test.java

```
@RequestMapping("test")
public ModelAndView test(@PathVariable Date testDate){
      // testDate = 09.02.2017 23:00:00
}
```

Example: I choose in datapicker (bootstrap) 10.02.2017 (№1) and get testDate in Controller (№2) 09.02.2017 23:00:00.

I think Spring or java.util.Date is converted testDate to server TimeZone. But I can be wrong

How send Date value to Spring Controller from bootstrap datepicker on jsp with client TimeZone? I shoud get 10.02.2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for me. 
Date type value converted Spring.
I have wrote:

```
public class DateConverter implements Converter<String, Date> {

@Override
public Date convert(String source) {
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    if (!source.isEmpty()){
      try {
        return sf.parse(source);
      } catch (ParseException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and add to class @Configuration

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new DateConverter());
}
```

Of course may override metod convert differently